# How to execute a loop until a value hits a number of the users choice

Tags: java

I am working on a project where i have to code a bmi chart, the user inputs a minimum weight and a maximum and the loop should run until the maximum weight. It goes by increments of 5 but im not sure how to make the loop stop at said so maximum weight number. For this example the minimum weight is 120 and the max is 155 so i would need the loop to end at 155 but it goes all the way to 250. So far this is the loop i came up with.

```
 for (int i=0; i<max; i+=5) {
            double newWeight = weight + i;

            double newBmi = ((newWeight * 703) / (height * height));

            String condition = null;

            if (newBmi < 18.5) {
                condition = "Underweight";
            }
            else if (newBmi >= 18.5 && newBmi < 25){
                condition = "Normal";
            }
            else if (newBmi >= 25 && newBmi < 30) {
                condition = "Overweight";
            }
            else if (newBmi >= 30) {
                condition = "Obese";
            }
            System.out.println(newWeight + "  " + newBmi + " " + condition);
            }
```

and this is the output

```
WEIGHT                   BMI                     CONDITION
120.0                      20.595703125                      Normal
125.0                      21.453857421875                      Normal
130.0                      22.31201171875                      Normal
135.0                      23.170166015625                      Normal
140.0                      24.0283203125                      Normal
145.0                      24.886474609375                      Normal
150.0                      25.74462890625                      Overweight
155.0                      26.602783203125                      Overweight
160.0                      27.4609375                      Overweight
165.0                      28.319091796875                      Overweight
170.0                      29.17724609375                      Overweight
175.0                      30.035400390625                      Obese
180.0                      30.8935546875                      Obese
185.0                      31.751708984375                      Obese
190.0                      32.60986328125                      Obese
195.0                      33.468017578125                      Obese
```

and it goes on until 270.. how do i get it to stop at whatever number the user inputs?

Answer (score 0):

Your condition in the loop is not correct because you check that the *difference* between the current weight is below `max`, not the calculated weight itself.  Therefore the loop runs until the difference is 150, that is for the min `weight = 120` it runs until 270 is reached.

So the loop should be rewritten without redundant variable `i`:

```java
for (double newWeight = weight; newWeight < max; newWeight += 5) {
     double newBmi = newWeight * 703 / (height * height);
// the rest of the code 
}
```

Also, formatted output `System.out.printf` could be used to print the table in a prettier way.